# Understanding sass mixins

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have seen a few sass compass tutorials. However, I am having to tweak a sass file from someone else and I can not find out what they did. I do not understand what the + symbol is doing here. I want to say it is similar to the @ sign but I can ot find anything that explains it. It is related to singularity? compass?

```
/* Main */
#main
  +tablet-wide
    +grid-span(18,1)
  +desktop
    +grid-span(24,1)
```

If you know of a good explanation or link please share. Trying to learn and reverse engineer at the same time.

Thanks

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17590280/1652962

Comment: Thanks for the links! I know more about the two now. I still don't under stand the +tablet-wide. Is that a variable like $tablet-wide?

Comment: No.  Look closer look at the animated gif in the 2nd link.  `+foo` is equivalent to `@include foo`.

Comment: Aha! Thanks. I think what was making it confusing was that the code from the other dev was missing variables for certain things. That was throwing me off since I assumed something else I didn't know was happening. Appreciate it!